# Open documents in Document Library using windows application

Tags: javascript, office-365, 2016, html, explorer-view

I want to open the documents in the SharePoint  Document Library using the windows application.

I am showing the list of documents with their links using an HTML/angular application

Now the problem is when the user clicks on the link, I don't want the file to be downloaded. I want the file to open with windows application so that user can edit and save it back.

For example, if the file is a PS1 file, then I want it to be opened with Photoshop(or ask the user to select the application the file has to be opened with) so that they can edit and save it back.

I tried using the below code

```
 <a href="tel:https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx">Open Document</a>
```

This will ask the user to select the application. I want to achieve something like this.

I also tried using ActiveXObjects in javascript, but nothing worked. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/xzb001tw/2/) is the fiddle